# Xamarin. The name 'authorEntry does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to add information to `Book` class then display information using `displayalert()` method and its worked. But Why got an error? Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

**NewBookPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Form.NewBookPage">
        <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0">

            <Entry x:Name="nameEntry"
                Placeholder="name of the book"/>

            <Entry x:Name="authorEntry"
                   Placeholder="name of the author"/>

        <Button Text="save"
               Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**NewBookPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Form
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewBookPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewBookPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Book book = new Book()
            {
                Name =  nameEntry.Text,
                Author = authorEntry.Text

            };
            DisplayAlert("Success",book.Name+"/"+book.Author, "great!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Error List**
[image]

**Image**

[image]

Comment: sorry and its wont happen again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Clean your project

2.Rebuild it, change your XAML file properties (Build Action) from Embedded Resource to Compile, Rebuild your project (will throw errors).

3.switch back your XAML file properties to Embedded Resource, Rebuild.

Refer to this link: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96447/the-name-initializecomponent-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context